# While making a Weather app in Android Studio using Java. Its not fetching data from API, it always execute 'onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)' method

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley, weather-api

I am trying to fetch weather details from weatherapi using Volley for JSON parsing but my code isn't fetching weather details instead it's executing the below code :

```
new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter valid city name...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This is the code(below) I used to fetch weather details from API but becoz of some error that is unknown to me it is executing onErrorResponse() method.

```
private void getWeatherInfo(String cityName){

    String url = "http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=API_KEY&q="+cityName+"&days=1&aqi=no&alerts=no";
    cityNameTV.setText(cityName);
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            loadingPB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            homeRL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            weatherRVModalArrayList.clear();

            try {
                String temperature = response.getJSONObject("current").getString("temp_c");
                temperatureTV.setText(temperature+"°c");
                int isDay = response.getJSONObject("current").getInt("is_day");
                String condition = response.getJSONObject("current").getJSONObject("condition").getString("text"); //returns the condition of the day mist or sunny or rainy etc
                String conditionIcon = response.getJSONObject("current").getJSONObject("condition").getString("icon");
                Picasso.get().load("http:".concat(conditionIcon)).into(iconIV); //here we are loading the icon in IconImage View
                conditionTV.setText(condition);
                if(isDay==1){

                    Picasso.get().load("https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/925716/screenshots/3333720/attachments/722376/after_noon.png").into(backIV);

                }
                else{
                    Picasso.get().load("https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/925716/screenshots/3333720/attachments/722375/night.png").into(backIV);

                }

                JSONObject forecastObj = response.getJSONObject("forecast");
                JSONObject forecastO = forecastObj.getJSONArray("forecastday").getJSONObject(0);
                JSONArray hourArray = forecastO.getJSONArray("hour");

                for(int i=0; i<hourArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject hourObj = hourArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String time = hourObj.getString("time");
                    String temper = hourObj.getString("temp_c");
                    String img = hourObj.getJSONObject("condition").getString("icon");
                    String wind = hourObj.getString("wind_kph");
                    weatherRVModalArrayList.add(new WeatherRVModal(time, temper, img, wind));

                }
                weatherRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter valid city name...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Let me know if more details are required regarding this.

Comment: What does the volley error say the error is?  Also, I'd really strongly recommend Retrofit over Volley.  It has a lot less boilerplate and a lot fewer weird gotchas.

Comment: Could you please add logs or error description to the question

Comment: ``onErrorResponse: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to api.weatherapi.com not permitted``
It shows the above error when I added a Log.d and error.getMessage() method to see the error message inside the ``public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)``